# hardlink invalid argument error

Tags: linux

I'm using the linux `ln` command to create a hardlink.

However, for some files I would get the error message "Invalid Argument"

My guess is that there is a pre-condition on the source file that I am not aware of.

I read the man pages and didn't read anything that helped.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Try running `strace ln file1 file2`.  That should show which system call failed.  "Invalid argument" is a very strange error for `ln`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't get my version of `ln` to say *just* "Invalid Argument"; it always gives me helpful error messages when I try to do something wrong.  You should do `alias ln` see if it's aliased to something else, and `which ln` to see if you're using something other than `/bin/ln`.  If it turns out that you are using `/bin/ln`, since your version isn't being helpful with its error messages, you could try doing [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) on `ln` to see what's going on:

```
strace -f -F -e trace=file -o ln.log ln FOO BAR
egrep 'FOO|BAR' ln.log
```

For example, if I try to do a cross-filesystem hard-link to `/dev/zero`, I get:

```
30835 linkat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/zero", AT_FDCWD, "./zero", 0) = -1 EXDEV (Invalid cross-device link)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've received the same error when trying to create links on read-only filesystems.

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘name’: Invalid argument
```

Try `touch`ing a file to see if the filesystem is writable.